# how to convert mongo db query in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

We have created MongoDB query but it's not converted into PHP

MongoDB query

```
db.crawled_jobs.aggregate(
 [ 
   {   
       $geoNear: { 
           near: {  
              type: "Point", 
              coordinates: [-73.86, 41.07 ] 
           }, 
           distanceField:"dist.calculated", 
           maxDistance: 100000, 
           includeLocs: "dist.location", 
           num: 1225, 
           spherical: true,
           "query": { "title": /sales/ } 
       } 
   }
])
```

Mongodb query working fine and we get results

In php `\MongoDB\Driver\Command`

Create an array in PHP and use for MongoDB query

```
$queryString = [['$geoNear'=> ['near'=> [ 'type'=> "Point",'coordinates'=> [$lon,$lat] ], 'distanceField'=> "dist.calculated",'maxDistance'=> $maxDistance, 'includeLocs'=> "dist.location", 'num'=> 10000, 'spherical'=> true, 'query' => ['title' => '/sales/'] ] ] ];
```

after this query, MongoDB query look like this

```
db.crawled_jobs.aggregate([{"$geoNear":"near":"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.86,41.07]},"distanceField":"dist.calculated","maxDistance":100000,"includeLocs":"dist.location","num":1225,"spherical":true,"query":{"title":"\/sales\/"}}}])
```

We didn't get result because it add backslash in query
 `"query":{"title":"\/sales\/"}
But we need like this "query": { "title": /sales/ }`

Can anyone help us

`\MongoDB\Driver\Command` does not accept string :( it require the only array not string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it  with this

```
'query' => ['title'=> array('$regex' => 'NYC')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [MongoDB\BSON\Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-regex.php) class to generate regex as following:

```
'query' => ['title' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('sales')]
```

Comment: MongoDB\BSON\Regex::__construct() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: after use this i get this "query":{"title":{}}

Comment: What is yours `php -v | head -1` and `php -i | grep Mongo` ? I tested it only with 5.6 + 1.2.3.